# Not authorized to access mutation in GraphQl

Tags: vue.js, graphql, authorization, aws-amplify

I am new to graphql. In my Vuejs application, which uses AWS Amplify, I am trying to save a user to my database after a new user signs up for an account. I took care of the AWS Amplify flow to add this new user to our Cognito pool. I wrote this code to store the user data in our database.

```
<template>
    <div>
        A page for testing graphQl queries and mutations
        <button @click.prevent="addUser()">Execute query</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { API } from 'aws-amplify'

    export const createUser = `
    mutation createUser {
      createUser(input: {
        firstName: "Tina",
        email: "Tina@gmail.com"
      }) {
        id firstName
      }
    }
    `
    export default {
      name: 'TestGraphQL',
      data() {
        return {
          data: null,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        addUser() {
          console.log('executing query')
          API.graphql({ query: createUser }).then(
            (response) => (this.data = response.data.createUser),
          ).catch(error => console.log('error: ' + error))
        },
      },
    }
    </script>
```

As you can see, for now I have hardcoded some user data in the function just to make sure I can add a user to the database. After this works, I plan to modify the mutation code to allow input variables that contain real user data.

I have run into an issue with authorization. Here is the error message I am seeing:

> "Not Authorized to access createUser on type User"

If I log into AWS Appsync > Queries with this user account, I can execute this same mutation and see the same error.

No authorization should be required to add a user to the database. How do I modify my schema or mutation code to not require authorization?

This documentation describes the effect of the @auth decorator. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/js
But where can I find this file in my repository? Or is this a file that I can edit through the AWS dashboard? I think it is called the 'schema'.

Comment: Could this question be written in pure javascript? I feel like graphql experts would be more likely to help if so

Comment: After going into the Cognito dashboard and adding the logged in user to the Public user group, this resolved the authorization error.

Comment: Your solution does not make a lot of sense.
Public is UnAuth'd, user group is Auth'd.
Apply a well written answer, and select it as the answer.

WHat it seems like you did is you added the Logged in user to the guest pool???